# Python: (uniform) sampling from a rectangle

Tags: python, random

Say I have a rectangle `[a,b]x[c,d]`, where `a,b,c,d` are reals.
I would like to produce `k` points `(x,y)` sampled uniformly from this rectangle, i.e. `a <= x <= c` and `b <= y <= d`.
Obviously, if sampling from `[0,1]x[0,1]` is possible, then
the problem is solved. How to achieve any of the two goals, in `python`?
Or, another tool such as `R`, for example?

Comment: `random.uniform()`? I suspect that you didn't look at the documentation very thoroughly before posting. `[(random.uniform(a,b),random.uniform(c,d)) for _ in range(k)]` works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.uniform()`:

```
import random

x, y = random.uniform(a, b), random.uniform(c, d)
```

If you want k of them a list comprehension will do

```
coords = [(random.uniform(a, b), random.uniform(c, d)) for _ in range(k)]
```

Answer (score -1):

I think modulo operator (%) is your friend to check if x and y are in [a,c] and [b,d]

If you can't use random between 2 numbers (others 0 and 1), you can try to make `x = (random() *(c-a)+a)`
Same with y :)

EDIT : Oh, i send it just after Merig